# Consistent Flash Player Crash ONLY on YouTube

Tags: flash, plugins, youtube

It could be similar to one of the bugs listed on LaunchPad (#689158), but may not be.  Basically, I used to occasionally get a crash on YouTube and opening a new browser or rebooting (don't remember which) took care of the problem.  However, now, EVERY time I try to open a video on YouTube, I get the frowning  block and the message, "The Adobe Flash plugin has crashed."  However, Hulu would also call for Adobe, right?  But I can see videos there.

Comment: You don't even need a flash player to use youtube! You just need a browser thst can handle html5! Btw flash isn't that great, html is the future! :)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use [Minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube)

Its a Flash Free Youtube Player.
It has a nice UI and works well on older systems

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be found at http://www.bwebcentral.com/cms/drupal/node/6560

basically you turn off hardware acceleration in the Adobe Settings.

1. Go to: http://www.youtube.com/my_speed#
2. Find the "Show Test Video" and follow the link. A video should come up.
3. Right Click the Video Window. A dialog should appear.
4. Click: "Settings...". A small window opens.
5. At the bottom of this window you will find icons. click the first icon on the left.
6. Uncheck "enable hardware acceleration."
7. That's it.

More info here: hxxp://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1699227